# set a timer before user can tap on a button ios

Tags: ios, uibutton, nstimer

I need help to set a timer on a button. Now I have this code,

```
- (IBAction)btnPlaySound:(id)sender {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileUrlRef;
    soundFileUrlRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"", CFSTR(""), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileUrlRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

and I want that the user can tap on this button only once every 2 seconds, I have to insert a `NSTimer` I think but in which way?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `(CFStringRef)@"word"` in the one case and `CFSTR("mp3")` in the other? Be consistent, here both of them are a string literal, so it's better to use `CFSTR()` for both uses.

Comment: ok thanks next time i leave it blank :)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerAction
{

    if (myButton.userInteractionEnabled == YES) {
        //do something
    }

    if ([myButton.tag == 0) {
        [myTimer invalidate];
        [myButton setTag:2];
        myButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }else{
        myButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        int currentTime = myButton.tag;
        int newTime = currentTime - 1;
        [myButton setTag:newTime];
    }

}
```

In order for the above code to work, you will need the declare a `NSTimer` named "myTimer" and a `UIButton` "myButton". You will also need to set the buttons initial tag to "2".